# Tie a custom savebutton to itemtemplate textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
using Visual.Web.Developer.2010.Express;
using SQL.Server.Management.Studio.2008.R2;
using Northwind;
```

N00b here,
Trying to customize a asp.net `gridview`, and I'm stuck at this part...

In the `ItemTemplate`, I've got a text-box that has a class applied to it where on `.keypress`(Clientside JS), a `asp:LinkButton` appears next to it that's formatted like a Jquery UI icon. I'm stuck at this part. I know that I can "enable editing" for the gridview, but I want to make an edit button only appear on `.keypress`, which I’ve already achieved. The park I’m stuck at is trying to get the click of that `asp:LinkButton` to send an update command to the SQLserver to update that db entry accordingly . So far, I’ve got the textbox to be created dynamically for each db item in that column.
Is there a more practical way of doing this while achieving the same results? To be more specific, I'm not really looking for code, cause I'm trying to learn, but more for methods I should take a look at, or other tutorials that I missed on the web.
[image]
 I would also appreciate some advice, thanks in advance: )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using GridView_RowCommand event to fetch the Command event bubbled by Linkbutton.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CommandName` Property of the `LinkButton` and set it to Update.

```
<Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:linkbutton ID="Button1" text="TextBox1" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
```